# Send data from Host App to Chrome Extension

Tags: c, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-native-messaging

After hours of work, I'm able to run a extension and the host app when I activate the extension, but everytime I try to receive data, I get undefined.

This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char message[] = "{\"t\": \"t\"}";

    unsigned int len = strlen(message);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);

    printf("%c%c%c%c", (char) 10, (char) 0, (char) 0, (char) 0);

    printf("%s", message);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Olaf Please make that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`%c` takes an `int` argument (*intrpreted* as `unsigned char`), not a `char`. That can/will result in wrong data being printed. Also `strlen` returns a `size_t`. You should read the man-pages of the functions you use.

**Important:** When passing binary values (not characters), you should either use `uint8_t` or - at least `unsigned char`. Remember that `char` can be signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. That might lead to surprises on arithmetic operations.

Note:

```
printf("%c%c%c%c", (char) 10, (char) 0, (char) 0, (char) 0);
printf("%s", message);
```

Can be combined (casts removed):

```
printf("%c%c%c%c%s", 10, 0, 0, 0, message);
```

If there is no library to support, you should think about writing some functions to serialize some basic types like:

```
static void print_u32(uint32_t value)
{
    for ( size_t n = 0 ; n < 4 ; n-- ) {
        putc((unsigned char)value);  // still passing an int !
        value >>= 8;
    }
}

... print_string( ...

print_u32(strlen(message));
print_string(message);
```

Note that `_setmode` is not a standard library function. After some googling, it seems to be a BSD extension also supported by Windows (just in case you want that extension to be portable).

Comment: _"Also, are you sure you want to printf the value 0 and not the digit '0'?"_ Reasonably sure; it's supposed to be message length in native byte order. See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol).

Comment: @Xan: I just was not sure, as I do not know the messaging API. So I added this as it is a common mistake of beginners. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Thanks for the help. According to the API, I must print the number of bytes in a 32 bits little endian value, followed by my JSON message.

Comment: @user5046765: If that helped, please consider accepting and/or upvoting. That's how to say thank you on Stack Overflow.